# TableView crashes when swiped beyond start

Tags: crash, tableview, swipe

One of my TableViews crashes when a swipe downwards would tend to scroll it to earlier than its start. The error is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[kitios.VersesTableViewController refreshVerseItems:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105155780'
```

kitios is the name of my app, VersesTableViewController is the custom class for the TableView controller, but my code does not have any function named refreshVerseItems. This is extremely puzzling!

What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Months ago when learning how to cope with adding a row into the TableView I tried using a value changed event; but found a better way, deleted the @IBAction refreshVerseItems() function from the Swift code, but forgot to delete the valued changed action from the storyboard. Forgetting to remove that bit from the storyboard "came back to haunt me"! Problem is now fixed.